# What's the name of position-setting spring clips used in plumbing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Could someone tell me if there's a general name for the kind of spring clips that slide onto a rod and set a position for some other attached element. I've seen them on sinks and toilet tanks -- here are pictures:

[image: toilet float level setter]

[image: Sink stopper lever position adjustment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some searching it seems that style of clip is limited to toilet hardware like you have shown.

A google reverse image search found the [originating site](http://www.prettyhandygirl.com/repairing-pop-up-sink-drain/) of your first image. They call it a "joint clamp clip" but a [join clamp clip on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_clip) says "Joint clips are used to prevent a joint from separating during a reaction process" so that name does not fit.

Many niche industries and unique devices do not have names even if the device is very old. I'm sure various plumbers refer to this clip in many different ways. From my experience in construction, the names are often unintelligent, named after a specific brand of that product, racist, sexist, or overlap with another industry.

When I am creating engineering documentation and I see a new device that does not have an obvious, appropriate, or searchable name; I will often create a name for it. If the name is logical and valuable, searchable documentation is spread with that name; it may very well become the industry standard name for it.

Here potential names for it. If you like one of them set it as the alt text for your image; and you may have just named it ;-)

1. rod retention clasp
2. adjustable rod retention clasp
3. rod retention clip
4. adjustable rod retention clip
5. float retention clip
6. adjustable float retention clip
7. float retention clasp
8. adjustable float retention clasp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the name I want would focus on the principle, not on the application. For example it's the same idea used in furniture clamps, like this Pony clamp that slides on a pipe: http://blog.edisonnation.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Pony-Tools-Clamp.jpg

Comment: Gotcha, I am still not finding anything. Perhaps a "directinal linear friction lock" or in your first example an "adjustable linear friction lock"

Comment: "Friction lock" is probably as general as you could go. "Spring applied friction lock" may distinguish it from your second example of a "manually applied friction lock".

Comment: You missed a good one in your list of naming conventions.  If it doesn't seem racist, sexist or unintelligible, it's likely named after a specific brand name product instead of a standard name for the part.

Comment: Most places where I've been involved in naming of components, the naming conventions have been to start with the most generic term first. So it would be Clip Retention Adjustable Float. Which seems dumb until you realize that lots of early parts catalogs were stored in alphabetical order by part name. So when kept in alphabetical order, all of the "clip" parts would be together and all of the retention clips in sub order within those and so on. Now though, computers index and search for us easily and such naming conventions are less useful.

Comment: Well, I awarded the answer, though I'm not entirely satisfied.  I think the mechanical principle involved is reasonably termed "jamming" or "binding". These are special cases of friction, in which there's some mechanical circumstance where increasing the force in the direction of interest also increases the friction. However, in a google search, combining either of those two terms with "clip" is quite unrewarding :-(.